# Specifying ecoregion

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract an ecoregion specified in the [Ecoregions 2017 Resolve Data](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/RESOLVE_ECOREGIONS_2017) in Google Earth Engine in order to then to examine forest loss and gain (using the Hansen data set) from that ecoregion (tapajos xingu in Brazil). How do I specify the ecoregion tapajos xingu in the Ecoregions 2017 Resolve Data in Google Earth Engine?

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017') .map(function(f) { 
  var c = ee.String(f.get('COLOR')).slice(1); 
  return f .set('R', ee.Number.parse(c.slice(0, 2), 16)) 
  .set('G', ee.Number.parse(c.slice(2, 4), 16)) .set('B', ee.Number.parse(c.slice(4, 6), 16)); 
}); 

var base = ee.Image(0).mask(0).toInt8(); 

Map.addLayer(base.paint(fc, 'R') .addBands(base.paint(fc, 'G') .addBands(base.paint(fc, 'B'))), {gamma: 0.3});
```

This is the code for Ecoregions 2017 Resolve Data

Comment: How do I specify the ecoregion tapajos xingu in the Ecoregions 2017 Resolve Data in google earth engine?

Comment: var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017')
  .map(function(f) {
    var c = ee.String(f.get('COLOR')).slice(1);
    return f
      .set('R', ee.Number.parse(c.slice(0, 2), 16))
      .set('G', ee.Number.parse(c.slice(2, 4), 16))
      .set('B', ee.Number.parse(c.slice(4, 6), 16));
  });

var base = ee.Image(0).mask(0).toInt8();
Map.addLayer(base.paint(fc, 'R')
  .addBands(base.paint(fc, 'G')
  .addBands(base.paint(fc, 'B'))), {gamma: 0.3});

This is the code for Ecoregions 2017 Resolve Data